# Why won't this C code create a file with user, group and other permissions read and write?

Tags: c, linux

Why won't the following code create a file with permissions read and write for user, group, and other?

```
   char data[10] = "123456789";
   int fh = open("test.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
   write(fh, data, 10);
   printf(strerror(errno));
   close(fh);
```

Produces this file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pc users       9 Nov 15 16:15 test.txt
```

What does that mean? I specifically asked for r+w in all categories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reset your [user mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) using the `umask()` system call before calling `open()`.

Comment: +1. From the manual: "permissions in the umask are turned off from the mode argument to open(2)"

Comment: here is the exact call: umask(0000); Thanks :)